# Relation between QField attribute forms

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have two columns for field data collection which reference one another using when/then CASEs in the "Default Value" of the Attribute Form. The CASE converts one measurement to the other. This is because some field workers collect compass measurements in Strike/Dip while others use Dip/Dip Direction. This expression insures the "Strike" column receives a value, which controls symbolization.  The first default value, for "Strike"

```sql
CASE
WHEN   "Dip_Direct"  < '90' THEN  "Dip_Direct" + '270'
WHEN  "Dip_Direct" >= '90' THEN  "Dip_Direct" - '90'
END
```

the second, for "Dip Direction"

```sql
CASE
WHEN   "Strike"  < '270' AND  "Dip" < '90' THEN  "Strike" + '90'
WHEN  "Strike" >= '270' AND  "Dip" < '90' THEN     "Strike" - '270'
END
```

This works well in QGIS, either column can be filled and the other is completed by the default expression however in QField, this locks one of the forms from editing. Only the Dip Direction field can be filled and saved.

I have attempted

1. unchecking the 'Apply default value on update'
2. adding IS/ IS NOT NULL values to the expression
3. enabling Fast Editing Mode in QField

Answer (score 1):

This live update of the default values has worked so far 'accidentally' in the fast edit mode, because there a value is saved immediately after its adjustment. However, this apparently does not cause any feedback to adjust default values again.

Anyway, in the upcoming QField Version 2 the live update funtionality will not only work 'accidentally in fast edit mode', but is implemented fully in the normal mode as well.

So test your project with the current beta release 2.0.3.